# Dynamic sitemap

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitemap

I want real example about dynamic site map take it's value from database

Comment: Pretty sure the button said "ask a question", not "make a demand" when you clicked it...maybe they changed it recently?

Comment: @Nick, he's been a member for only 14 days!!!  I think we can be a lot more hospitable to new members, for instance NOT downvoting an innocuous post.

Comment: @code4life - Wasn't my downvote :)  Look at my profile, you'll see I do that *very* rarely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build a custom map provider:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163657.aspx

About the real example that you're looking for I suggest to google: [sitemap from database asp.net](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=sitemap+from+database+asp.net&aq=0&aqi=g1&aql=f&oq=sitemap+from+database+a&gs_rfai=&fp=a2bb30ecf4f91972)